# React Native Android - development server response error code 500

Tags: android, react-native

Learning react-native and currently following IG clone tutorial on my android device from this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgg1HidN4mQ

I have come stuck in this. Attached image is something I've been trying to fix for hours with no luck...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/THcUb.jpg

Does anybody know what would be the cause of this? Here is the code...

https://github.com/crt434/React_IG_Copy

Comment: You are trying to import components from `AppTabNavigator` folder but your repo doesn't have any folder named like that or component files that you are trying to import.

Comment: Thanks :) sorry for the level 1 questions :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this code in your Mainscreen.js

```
import HomeTab from './AppTabNavigator/HomeTab'
import SearchTab from './AppTabNavigator/SearchTab'
import AddMediaTab from './AppTabNavigator/AddMediaTab'
import LikesTab from './AppTabNavigator/LikesTab'
import ProfileTab from './AppTabNavigator/ProfileTab'
```

All these paths are missing. there is no AppTabNavigator folder.

Comment: Appreciate the help, understand this was a silly question. I should of noticed :)

Comment: in new react native project there is no Mainscreen,js, I only have app.js and index.js, where should copy this code then!? , I'm trying to get first output of react and I faced same stupid error...